# Debug print statements in fortran program running with MPI only showing up for first process

Tags: multithreading, multidimensional-array, fortran, mpi, openmpi

I have a fortran program that uses the [mpi functionality of the fftw library](https://fftw.org/doc/Distributed_002dmemory-FFTW-with-MPI.html) to split up computations on a large tensor-like data structure among multiple processes. This library has functions that output the offset on a defined axis on the tensor in question and the amount of items each process is assigned on this axis, which may differ for each process. I have added debug print statements to my program to see if the values corresponding to each process are the same, but only get the output of process 0 instead of all four processes when executing my program as following:

```
mpiexec -n 4 my_fortran_binary
```

Is there a way to also access the print output of the three other processes? If not, is there a better way to debug functions such as [this one](https://fftw.org/doc/2d-MPI-example.html) in terms of the outputs for the variables `&local_n0` and `&local_0_start`?

Comment: Without an example code showing the issue this is very difficult to answer. Do you *know* the other processes have written something? Could they be waiting elsewhere before the writing starts? What happens if you write the data to a file and put a `Flush` after every write? I'm afraid there are a multitude of variables here, and any one of them could be the key

Comment: I'd also like to know what kind of system the program is running on.  Some big iron doesn't connect all processes to the console.